# Stick a `*` to the closest next word during the parsing

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I have the following line in the text:

```
int* a, b;
```

The expected result is:

```
int *a, b;
```

The following `Perl` code is supposed to produce the expected line:

```
$line =~ s#\s*\*\s*#\s\*#g;
```

Unfortunately, the result is the following:

```
int*a, b;
```

What is wrong in the regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change:

```
$line =~ s#\s*\*\s*#\s\*#g;
```

by:

```
$line =~ s#\s*\*\s*# \*#g;
```

`\s` is invalid in the replacement part.

Comment: @Alex: as Amadan said, `\s` means a character class that represents all "space" character.

Comment: @Alex, the right side of `s///` is treated as a string, not as a regex

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can use `\s` in replacement; it represents a character class (whitespace, including spaces, tabs etc) in search, but a class makes no sense in replacement. Use a normal space.

Comment: More specifically, the replacement part of a substitution is just an ordinary double-quoted string, with the escape codes of a double-quoted string. Strings and Regexes have different (though overlapping) sets of escapes. The `\s` is a regex-only escape representing a character class.

Answer (score -1):

Try this too.

```
$line =~ s/(\S)\*(?=\s+)\s*/$1 \*/;
```